# .Net Winform Apps with Portrait Monitor

Tags: .net, winforms, monitor, portrait

I have noticed an undesirable behavior with .net winforms applications. I have a wide screen monitor rotated 90 degrees to the portrait orientation. When .net winforms applications display on it, the window appears, but it is all blank, white. I can fix the window by hitting ctrl-alt-delete and when the dialog comes up, hitting cancel, then the window will display properly. I have duplicated this on different monitors and video cards. I have seen this both with a home grown app and with the Windows Update screen. It does need to be a wide screen monitor, however. A "square" monitor rotated 90 degrees doesn't seem to have this issue. Has anyone else observed this? Is there a fix for it? Is it a known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is being started *after* the monitor rotate? Because I'm calling fowl on Microsoft here. I think their font stuff is all messed up and thats why.

Comment: Yes the application is run by shortcut, whenever.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen nor noticed that before, and I used to sell rotating screens like that when I used to work for Circuit City.

Regardless, have you tried running me.refresh()? (or this.Refresh(); depending on the language) it simply makes the form redraw.  Might be worth trying to put that line of code in the formResize event handler to see if it helps anything.

Also, I assume it goes without question that your anchors are set up correctly.  So the last thing I can think of at the moment is checking to make sure that the .Location properties of the form controls describe a point within the page bounds when its not showing up.

Oh, this could also be an OS thing... are we talking XP? Vista? Windows 7? or just all Microsoft products?